# Snap window shortcuts in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I come from Ubuntu 16.04 + Unity, where key combinations like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad-6</kbd> would snap the focused window to the right of the current screen, *and* make the window fill half of the screen horizontally.
Similarly <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad-3</kbd> would make it snap to the lower right corner.

In Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome the <kbd>numpad-6</kbd> shortcut only snaps the window to the (far right) edge of all screens. Is there away to get the Unity behavior to Gnome?

Answer (score 2):

By way of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139730/gnome-shell-window-snap-to-quarters-of-screen), I found the [gtile gnome-shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/). So far it seems really good! You can check out the [docs on github](https://github.com/gTile/gTile) but it's quite powerful.

The keyboard shortcuts are a little different, so I'll provide a mapping to the old ones below:

- top left corner: <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 7</kbd>
- top right corner: <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 9</kbd>
- bottom left corner: <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 1</kbd>
- bottom right corner: <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 3</kbd>
- snap to top half of screen: <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 8</kbd>
- snap to bottom half of screen: <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 2</kbd>
- snap to right half of screen: (was <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 6</kbd>): <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>right-arrow</kbd>
- snap left half of screen (was <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>numpad 4</kbd>): <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>left-arrow</kbd>

There's lots of other keyboard shortcuts provided by that extension so it's worth checking out the docs I linked above!